# React full page image that disappears on scroll down, doesnt come back when you scroll up

Tags: reactjs

I have a main image that covers the screen, when i scroll just a little bit, i want to remove it. I dont want it to come back until you reload the page. I have tried many options including react-reveal and react-headroom, but i cant get them to work how i want. Thank you

Comment: The question is too broad. Please read this [ask] and this [mcve].

Comment: Can you show code of `main image`?

Comment: Its just a div right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple answer would be to listen scroll events and set a state on which you'll base your render function.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    scrolled: false,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  componentWillUnmout() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  handleScroll = () => this.setState({ scrolled: true });

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {!this.state.scrolled && <img src="..." />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If that works for you you'll want remove the event listener when already scrolled to avoid later performance issues, would look like this :

```
handleScroll = () => {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  this.setState({ scrolled: true });
}
```

Comment: this works great, thank you. Wonder if you could elaborate just a little bit on adding customization to the scroll effects. Thanks again